# What's wrong with my bielliptic transfer calculation?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, delta-v, geostationary, hohmann-transfer

I'm trying to calculate the delta-v needed to get from a 200 km circular orbit to a geostationary orbit. GSO is at an altitude of 42164140.1029448 m and at a speed of 3074.6611762 m/s. Because $\frac{42164140.1029448}{200000} = 210.82070051472402 > 15.58$, any bielliptic transfer should be more efficient than a Hohmann transfer.

Here is my Hohmann transfer math:
$$ v_{pe_1}=\sqrt{\mu\Bigg(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\Bigg)}=\sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{6571000}-\frac{1}{6571000}\Bigg)}\approx 7788.48798575474 \\ 
v_{pe_2} = \sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{6571000}-\frac{1}{21182070.0514724}\Bigg)}\approx 10245.15814427758578 \\
\Delta V_1=2456.67015852284578 \\
v_{ap}=\sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{6571000}-\frac{1}{21182070.0514724}\Bigg)} \approx 1596.639561525085 \\
\Delta V_2 = 1478.0216146749153 \\
\sum \Delta V = 3934.69177319776108$$

Here is my bielliptic transfer for a 500,000 km apogee kick:
$$v_{pe_2} = \sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{6571000}-\frac{1}{256471000}\Bigg)}\approx 10943.80722915345372 \\
\Delta V_1 = 3155.31924339871372 \\
v_{ap} = \sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{506571000}-\frac{1}{256471000}\Bigg)}\approx 139.8084419739 \\
v_{ap_2} = \sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{506571000}-\frac{1}{274367570.0514724}\Bigg)}\approx 347.739448805 \\
\Delta V_2 = 207.9310068311 \\
v_{pe_3}=\sqrt{3.9860044188\cdot10^{14}\Bigg(\frac{2}{42164140.1029448}-\frac{1}{274367570.0514724}\Bigg)} \approx 4177.83262958787 \\
\Delta V_3 = 1103.1714533878694 \\
\sum \Delta V = 4466.42170361768312$$

However, this contradicts the previous statement that any bielliptic transfer from a 200 km orbit to GSO is more efficient than a Hohmann. What's wrong with my math?

Comment: You need to work with absolute orbital height, not height above ground. The actual ratio of the orbits is about 6.5, not 210.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 200km altitude, the orbital radius is 6,378km (earth radius) + 200m, = 6,578km.

Geostationary orbit is at an orbital radius of 42,164km

That's a ratio of only 6.4, not above the limit of 11.94 for *some* bi-elliptic transfers becoming a viable option. So a Hohmann transfer will be both faster and cheaper.

Altitude must not be confused by distance to the centre of mass. Had your initial orbit been at 200km *radius*, well inside the core of the Earth, a bi-elliptic transfer would indeed (any, since it's >15.58) have been the best options. Ignoring all the liquid rock.

Comment: You'd have to ignore the explosion caused by the planet violently objecting to being compressed to a sphere less than 200km in radius.

Comment: I think OP actually uses the correct orbits in their calculations, its just in the initial test for efficiency of bi-elliptic that the 200km orbit was used. But this threw a spanner in the whole thought process.